# Choosing specific item from json file in case multiple fields have same name vba

Tags: json, excel, vba, api

i have data from an api (json formatted) , and a column in excel filled with article names, i did this so each time it finds the article in the api , it gets the price and puts it in the right cell in column price(it worked), I noticed that in this api an article could have multiple prices so i want to let the user choose (lowest , highest price etc), I did this and now im blocked , Any ideas on how i can do this plz , i only found .exist method to check for occurence but it only works on collections ...

**CODE SAMLPLE**

```
Sub prix()
Dim http As New WinHttpRequest
Dim resp As String
Dim url As String

url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/appY6Wo3AmLHqHkjr/Materiaux?api_key=key_here" & Fields
http.Open "GET", url, False
http.Send
Dim item As Object
Dim json As Object
Dim c As Long
Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.ResponseText)
Dim Found As Range
For Each item In json("records")
Set Found = Range("G:G").Find(item("fields")("description courte"))
If Not Found Is Nothing Then
c = c + 1 ' want to count how many times was the same "description courte" found
If c > 1 Then
UserForm1.Show
If UserForm1.OptionButton1.Value Then   'choose the one that has the most expensive price
If UserForm1.OptionButton2.Value Then
If UserForm1.OptionButton3.Value Then
Else:
Found.Offset(0, 3).Value = item("fields")("prix unitaire HT")
End If
End If
Next item
End Sub
```

**JSON SAMPLE**

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "rec0MS66BnYY0vK32",
      "fields": {
        "id": 124,
        "article": "osmo 24m2 3062MAT 0.75L",
        "categorie": [
          "recvw95DBiWvk3zaH"
        ],
        "udv": 1,
        "unité": [
          "recYQ9wpLDgNDk5BW"
        ],
        "prix HT de l'udv": 29.09,
        "date d'achat": "2019-08-01",
        "distributeur": "cotet mtp",
        "reference distributeur": "OSMO-ORI-0.75-M",
        "id facture": "FA19036300",
        "created on": "2020-02-07",
        "by": "remyvignaux",
        "description courte": "osmo 3062MAT",
        "prix unitaire HT": 29.09
      },
      "createdTime": "2021-02-28T20:53:00.000Z"
    },....etc
```

Comment: Do you have a spare column where you can store c for the value of `description courte` in Find.

Comment: @CDP1802 yea i can add a column if i want , feel free to tell me if u have an idea cuz i have none :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the count in .offset(0,1) and the highest in .offset(0,3). Optionally store all the prices in offset(0,4) onwards.

```vb
    Dim Found As Range, price As Double, count As Long
    For Each item In json("records")
        
        Set Found = Range("G:G").Find(item("fields")("description courte"))
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            count = Found.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
            price = item("fields")("prix unitaire HT")
            ' want to count how many times was the same "description courte" found
            If count > 1 Then
                If price > Found.Offset(0, 3).Value Then
                    Found.Offset(0, 3).Value = price
                End If
            Else
                Found.Offset(0, 3).Value = price
            End If
            Found.Offset(0, 3 + count).Value = price
            Found.Offset(0, 1).Value = count
        End If
    Next item
```

test json

```vb
{
  "records": [
    { "fields": {
        "description courte": "osmo 3062MAT",
        "prix unitaire HT": 29.09
    }},
    { "fields": {
        "description courte": "osmo 3062MAT",
        "prix unitaire HT": 40.00
    }},
    { "fields": {
        "description courte": "osmo 3062MAT",
        "prix unitaire HT": 10.00
    }}]
}
```

Comment: ok , im gonna try to work with this later , do u think its possible to put those values in option buttons and let the user choose one ? idk ill try and put it here if i managed ty

Comment: @Chayma Do you mean choose an aggregate function like max(), min(), average() or do you mean a particular price ? If selecting a price use a ListBox with values sorted in some way. For the aggregate, either OptionsButton or LIstBox. Is the selection made before or after the json is parsed ?.

Comment: @CPD1802 before , I cant use an aggregate function cuz the comparaison is going to be done before parsing the data , or else ill just show all the prices that exist in a list box (easier i think) and let the user choose one value then put in the column price , do u think its more doable ? it'll spare me sorting the prices before the parse

Comment: @Chayma *cuz the comparaison is going to be done before parsing the data* I don't understand,  comparison of what to what ?

Comment: for example i have "article" : one "price":50 and "article": one "price" : 70 etc i need to compare all the prices and option1 : choose lowest and highest price and ask the user to choose which one goes in the cell . option 2 : display all the prices and let him choose which one .I still havent decided which option im gonne do as i said my employer wants smth like this but he has 0 knowledge in cs (im an intern) so im gonna do the easy one and tell him thats all i can do